# SimpleSAMLphp redirect back with wrong hostname

Tags: simplesamlphp

I have an application at url like `https://mytestapp.domain`
Have there installed SimpleSAMLphp `https://mytestapp.domain/simplesaml`

When I want to log in I am redirected to SAML server where I can fill username and password. Then I am redirected back to my app.

Problem is that I am redirected to `https://<ip_of_my_server>/simplesaml/module.php/saml/sp/discoresp.php...` but I need hostname in url (`https://mytestapp.domain/simplesaml/module.php/saml/sp/discoresp.php...`)

In SAML request I have

```
<saml:Issuer>https://<ip_of_my_server>/simplesaml/module.php/saml/sp/metadata.php/...</saml:Issuer>

AssertionConsumerServiceURL="https://<ip_of_my_server>/simplesaml/module.php/saml/sp/saml2-acs.php/..."
```

But

```
entityID="https://mytestapp.domain/simplesaml/module.php/saml/sp/metadata.php/..."
```

and baseurl is also filled with hostname `https://mytestapp.domain...`

Can somebody direct me where I should change IP to hostname?

---

**Edit 1**

mytestapp.domain/simplesaml/admin/hostnames.php as Lisa suggested is 404 Not Found (maybe some older version on my server (it looks like it is 1.11)

In config.php I have

```
$config = array(
//...
'baseurlpath' => 'https://' . $currentHost . '/simplesaml/',
//...
);
```

where `$currentHost` is result of getting `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST` or `HTTP_HOST` and it is filled with `mytestapp.domain`

Comment: You can check the hostname configuration of SimpleSAMLPHP at:
https://mytestapp.domain/simplesaml/admin/hostnames.php

Perhaps the HTTP_HOST setting on your webserver should be updated?

Comment: After the information provided in the edit:
In config.php for SimpleSAMLPHP, check the name of the BaseUrl setting.
It seems like it should be:
'baseurlpath' => 'https://' . $currentHost . '/simplesaml/'

Comment: Oh, of course you're right and it is like that there. I stupidly wrote it by hand in the edit instead of copy it from the config file. Mixed with different project in my head.